# Sharepoint 2010 onpremise with a form which is available for anonymous people, how to avoid bots/spammers!

Tags: 2010, custom-form

I am using sharepoint 2010 onpremise for my public website. On this website I have build a webpart for my contact page with inside of it a form with some fields like: firstname, lastname, address, email, phonenumber etc. The website is available for anonymous people. I have enabled anonymous access on a list where data of the form will be saved as a listitem. In my custom webpart I send also an email to my email address. Now I receive very much emails of fake filled contact form. This are not human which filled this contact form, but spam bots. How can I avoid this bots?

Comment: Just like any other form in any other technology than SharePoint ;) captcha or other tool for the user to fill in validation text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented the original reCAPTCHA control. You need to add the reCAPTCHA dll as a reference and can add the control to your form. The dll needs to add as a safe control. This is possible in the package under the tab "advanced".

Answer (score 1):

Cant you just add an extra column where it asks the user to enter a text/number/character of any type, and then add an event handler on ItemAdding that checks if the specific field is matching what you asks for and then let the event continue, else cancels the event?

Or do the same in your custom webpart with a regular expression.

[Regular Expressions (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)